# How to resolve discussions where developers can't agree?

Tags: teamwork

Our organisation currently consists of 10 developers, I am one of the senior developers there.

We recently held a meeting, as one of the developers wanted to suggest using a different framework to what we are using now.

The discussion itself became very heated - with each developer trying to put across their opinion as to why their preferred framework is better than what someone else is suggesting.

The meeting was not conclusive in the sense that we did not reach any agreement and have decided to have a follow up meeting next week.

What is the best way to handle these discussions? Inevitability every developer will favour their own preferred framework and even if you narrow it down to 2/3 options, it is likely that no one option will hold a majority.

Should a senior developer make a decision on behalf of the team? Should these discussions be held with developers on an individual basis as opposed to a team discussion?

Comment: ...see also [What concrete steps can I take to assess PHP framework(s) without having to go to the extent of getting to know each framework in intimate detail?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/238221/what-concrete-steps-can-i-take-to-assess-php-frameworks-without-having-to-go-t)

Comment: @GSTAR - I modified the title and tags slightly to better match the question. Feel free to edit if it's inaccurate.

Comment: This question is not specific to developers. It happens with any group of workers when no one is accountable for the project overall.

Answer (score 7):

#### Who is [accountable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsibility_assignment_matrix)?

There should be ***one*** person who is the person accountable for a given project/task. They are the person with their head on the block should it fail. Sometimes that is an architect. Sometimes it's a team lead. Sometimes it's a manager. Sometimes it's just some developer.

But that one person gets to make the final call. And they're the one who gets to suffer if they make a bad one.

It sounds as though you don't have anyone who is accountable. I would encourage you to go to your boss, and make them do it. If they won't, see if they'll at least designate someone as being the accountable one. If they won't even do that, then it's up to your team to pick someone, somehow. I recommend Programmer Thunderdome.

Comment: Along with accountability is identifying the criteria for the framework.

Comment: Also be sure they're really going to be accountable when their new ideas don't work.

Comment: this sounds like the opposite of the agile mindset of shared ownership of the code. in companies like facebook, even when there's thousands of developers, they all own the code together. it's not "someone else's problem" and you don't do something half-assed because "it's not my head on the line if it fails". I think this is a very divisive mindset that promotes covering your ass instead of collaborating.

Comment: @kai - You seriously think people aren't held accountable for doing their work at Facebook? When nobody is responsible, it's always someone else's problem.

Comment: it's not that nobody is responsible. EVERYONE is responsible. the point is to build a culture where everyone owns and feels responsibility for every line of code in the code base. if a problem arises or a bug is found, the focus is not on finding a scapegoat to blame and shun, but in finding out what went wrong, and learning from the experience. this does NOT mean that people can slack off and do whatever they want with no repercussions. it's focusing on solving problems rather than keeping your back clear.

Comment: @kai - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_of_responsibility

Comment: @Telastyn yes, it is possible to have a team/company culture where no process is used to make sure deadlines are held or where no stakeholders or owners care at all about delivering, but this is then a deeper problem where the company has incompetent management. letting a bunch of individuals hack away with no communication or collaboration is NOT the same thing as shared responsibility. it's in the entire teams interest to deliver. if someone refuses to cooperate, obviously you fire them/don't hire them in the first place.

Comment: basically, you don't have to choose between "have a firing squad ready to shoot someone as soon as they make a mistake" and "let people do whatever they want with no consequence and never ever deal with problems". both of these are Bad, and quite frankly, strawmen.